# Symfony language when routing resources

Tags: symfony, localization, routes

I'm trying to use a _locale variable in a routing, and if is not set use the default locale. The routing looks like this:

```
#/app/config/routing.yml

xxx_yyy_zzz:
    resource: "@XYZBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /orientation/{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: %locale% }
```

What I'm trying to do is to be able to use "*domain.com/orientation/WhateverLanguage*" or "*domain.com/orientation*", but it doesn't work.

When I type "domain.com/orientation" I get a "No route found for "GET /orientation".

Am I missing something? Can this be done?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the output of the `app/console router:debug` command. Now, it's hard to guess whether `/orientation` is a matched route.

Comment: Obviously you don't define `/orientation` but `/orientation/` here.  You'll need to define an additional route for `/orientation` without the trailing `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have both routes as nifr says, but it still doesn't work, got the same result. kix, the route:debug output shows only routes matching with `/orientation/{_locale}` . I'm wondering if maybe I can't use `defaults:` values when I'm importing a resource ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this cookbook from the Symfony doc will help you.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html

Grtz

Comment: Thanks Cristophe for your response, I tried but got same result. I'm wondering that this is something related with the use of `resource`

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think convention is to put the locale at the beginning of the prefix `/{_locale}/orientation`